# Need Help with a new project

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am starting my first software engineering job in a week and wanted to sharpen my skills up.  I'm looking for someone to suggest a good week long, web application project that can help me sharpen up my C#, Javascipt, and JQuery.

Thanks!

Brandon

Edit:  As noted below this is a pretty broad question.  Let me give a little more background.  I am a strong programmer, but an entry level one.  My experience as an intern for a year gave me glimpses into a number of the .Net and C# technologies, but what I have never done was put them all together into an inclusive project.  I'm looking for a project idea that will have me setting up both client and server side code (purely for practice) that will provide me better insight into how each piece of the puzzle fits together.

Comment: Great point, I added an Edit note which hopefully clarifies a little.

Comment: A truly strong programmer never says they are a strong programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a blog engine. its useful, easy, and has bounded, easily understood requirements.

Comment: +1 Good point, we all do that ;)

Comment: yeah, its like the new "hello, world"

Answer (score 2):

You could start with one of the [ASP.NET Starter Kits](http://www.asp.net/downloads) and build upon it.

Answer (score 2):

Being that you have C# experience, I highly recommend trying Asp.Net MVC as I feel it is the future of MS Web programming (I am not alone in this opinion... though it is just an opinion).

If nothing else, the MVC (model-view-controller) organization is a well established and useful method of coding that is used accross all sorts of platforms like php, ruby on rails, etc. - not as much of an 'island' like Asp.Net WebForms (Asp.Net WebForms are still great).

There are all sorts of great tutorials, the most famous being [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)

Comment: Good advice, I actually spent last week going through MVC.  Unfortunately though, the software engineering firm I'm starting at will be using Asp.net rather than mvc

Comment: Just fyi... the terms are ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC. Both exist under the ASP.NET product name, and both can be used as part of the same web application.

Comment: @Greg, good point, updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out the materials available under the [jquery tag on Channel9](http://preview.channel9.msdn.com/Tags/jquery). There is a great video from PDC2008 that talks about [ASP.NET and jQuery](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC31/) and another [jQuery for the ASP.NET Developer](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/jQuery-for-the-ASPNET-Developer-by-Scott-Allen/) presentation from DevDays 2010.